# How to use makeSceneTransitionAnimation from adapter in fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have adapter liked in `fragment`.

In this adapter's part, if I click it, It moves to `Activity`.

Between adapter's itemView and Activity, there's shared element of ImageView.

And I want to apply shared element Animation.

So I add below `transitionName` in both xml of fragment item and Activity.

```
android:transitionName="avatarTransition"
```

And in fragment adapter's `onBindViewHolder`, I write code as below.

```
   holder.itemView.userAvatar.setOnClickListener { view ->
            val goEnlargeAvatar = Intent(context, EnlargeAvatarActivity::class.java)
            val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context, view, "avatarTransition")
            goEnlargeAvatar.putExtra("userAvatar", items[position].userAvatar)
            context.startActivity(goEnlargeAvatar, options.toBundle())
        }
```

The important part is `options`, but if I write this code, it throws error.

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity, View, String) defined in androidx.core.app.ActivityOptionsCompat
makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity, vararg Pair<View!, String!>!) defined in androidx.core.app.ActivityOptionsCompat
```

I think, `context` causes the problem here.

But in Fragment liked with adapter, I send context as `requireActivity()`.

```
   adapter = AllDiaryCardAdapter(requireActivity(), diaryItems)
```

Even if I send `Activity`, I don't know why it causes error.

And in this case, How can I apply this animation?

Please help me!